# how to short this PHP code?

Tags: php, while-loop, inner-join

i have three tables

```
id1 title1         id2 title2       id3 title3
1    ....          1    ....        1   .....
2     .....        2    .....       2    ....
3     ...          3   .....        3    ....
4    .....                          4    .... 
                                    5   .....
```

assume every **title1** has a few **title2** and every **title2** has a few **title3** inside them. i want an output as above

```
title1
  title2
    title3
    title3
  title2
    title3
  title2
    title3
    title3
    title3
------------
title1
  title2
    title3
  title2
    title3
    title3
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

while i am able to create this **(i use *JOINs)***. i am using three `$command = mysqli..` and 3 `while loops`. just like

```
$command = mysqli...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($command)){
  echo ..

  $command2 = mysqli...
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($command2)){
     echo ..

     $command3 = mysqli...
     while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($command3)){
        echo ..

     }
  }
}
```

others commented on my codes and said "is there any way not using three while loops" or "why are you calling your database three times?"

can you do it? 
is there any way make getting intented output in just one `mysqli_query()`?

Comment: you are right about title and not about clearity

Comment: @hellcode i have 3 join tables which i use for join statements. i did not show them here because i thougt you may create one JOIN table. i mean this is the question. how to create one JOIN table for one _query()_ ?

Comment: @hellcode my english is not good. i thougt like wikipedia has titles and every title has other sub-titles. what happened?

Comment: already answered that

Answer (score 0):

Let's join tables together:

```
SELECT t1.id id1, t1.title tit1, t2.id id2, t2.title tit2, t3.id id3, t3.title tit3 FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id =t2.pid JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id =t3.pid ORDER BY id1, id2, id3;
```

In PHP:

```
$tt1 = -1;
$tt2 = -1; 
$tt3 = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($command)){
if($row['id1'] != $tt1){
$tt1 = $row['id1'];
echo ( $row['tit1'];
}
if($row['id2'] != $tt2){
$tt2 = $row['id2'];
echo ( $row['tit2'];
}
if($row['id3'] != $tt3){
$tt3 = $row['id3'];
echo ( $row['tit3'];
}
}
```

I do not test it, cause I post from phone. I think it should works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of your tables has a key column that links it to its parent table you should be able to join them all together in one query like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT id1, title1, id2, title2, id3, title3 
        FROM table1
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id1 = table2.id1
        LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.id2 = table3.id2
        ORDER BY id1, id2, id3";
$command = mysqli_query($sql);
```

I am not certain of names of the foreign key columns, but this should be enough to give you an idea of what I mean.

Then you can construct a mulitidimensional array as you fetch your query results.

```
$tree = array();   
while ($row = mysli_fetch_object($command)) {
    $tree[$row->id1]['title'] = $row->title1;
    $tree[$row->id1]['subtitles'][$row->id2]['title'] = $row->title2;
    $tree[$row->id1]['subtitles'][$row->id2]['subtitles'][] = $row->title3;
}
```

Once you have that array, there are various ways you could choose to format it. This is a nested list, for example.

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($tree as $title1) {
    echo '<li>' . $title1['title'] . '<ul>';
    foreach ($title1['subtitles'] as $title2) {
        echo '<li>' . $title2['title'] . '<ul><li>';
        echo implode('</li><li>', $title2['subtitles']);
        echo '</li></ul></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

You can see from the repetition in these structures that if you added more levels it would make more sense to use a recursive function to generate the output.